# Offline Dictionary For iOS Multiple Languages

Tags: ios, dictionary, offline

Do we have any offline dictionary SDK for the iOS 
Also It needs to support for Multiple languages.
Kindly suggest if any.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No.
But alternatively you can encode a plain text file with your language and then use NSLocalizedstring to fetch the language's string via it's key.

For a depth tutorial you can look into [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)